# Desktop App Converter fails to launch

Tags: desktop-bridge

Everytime I try to run the Desktop App Converter I get the following error:

> The parameter is incorrect.

Same thing happens for any app I try to run using the desktop bridge. The rest of my Windows Store Apps works fine.

Kind of a bummer as we're looking to add some photo functionality to an older WPF app and hoping to take advantage of the WinRT camera API's.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround you can try:

From an elevated PowerShell window:

1. Navigate to 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\'
   (assuming you are using version 2.0.2.0 of the DAC)
2. From there, use the script DesktopAppConverter.ps1 script to run the DAC e.g 
   .\DesktopAppConverter.ps1 -Installer C:\Installers\myInstaller.msi -PackageName "myApp" -Version 1.0.0.0 -Destination "C:\Output\" -Publisher "CN=myPubID" -MakeAppx -Sign -Verbose

What Windows Build are you currently running? You can also try installing a Windows update if available.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can launch the Desktop App Converter from the folder and I get the following window.

Comment: Program 'DesktopAppConverter.exe' failed to run: The parameter is incorrectAt line:1 char:1

Comment: My core problem is the DAC and any application i try to run with the Desktop Bridge Debugging Project throws 'The parameter is incorrect.' error. I'm on Version 10.0.15063 Build 15063.